# PowerShell out-gridview cmdlet asks for PowerShell ISE but it is already installed

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the Out-GridView cmdlet on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box. It complains that it can't run because I need to install the Windows Powershell Integrated Scripting Environment feature. The problem is, that is already installed. Not sure what the problem is or how to troubleshoot this.

```
PS C:\Share\Jred\PowerShell> import-module servermanager
PS C:\Share\Jred\PowerShell> Get-WindowsFeature PowerShell-ISE

Display Name                                            Name
------------                                            ----
[X] Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environm... PowerShell-ISE


PS C:\Share\Jred\PowerShell> get-process | out-gridview
out-gridview : To use the Out-GridView cmdlet, install the Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment feature
from Server Manager. (Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalHost, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neu
tral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.)
At line:1 char:27
+ get-process | out-gridview <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...1bf3856ad364e35:AssemblyName) [Out-GridView], NotSupp
   ortedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ErrorLoadingAssembly,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand

PS C:\Share\Jred\PowerShell> Import-Module ServerManager; Add-WindowsFeature PowerShell-ISE

Success Restart Needed Exit Code Feature Result
------- -------------- --------- --------------
True    No             NoChan... {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to PowerShell 3.0 by following: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx and it started working. No idea why.

Comment: Out-Gridview was only introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: It seems that way. I also have found documentation that it is part of PowerShell 2. http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_out_gridview.htm

Comment: @ShaneWealti, possibly that reviewer was looking at a preview that never occurred? The official docs say v3+ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx

Comment: @AnneTheAgile, Thanks! I think I figured out what is going on. According to the link you posted, for non-server OS Powershell 2 included Out-Gridview by default but for server-OS it is not included until PowerShell 3. I was using a server OS so that explains why it didn't work in 2.